# Setting tick intervals on a D3 time axis throwing an exception

Tags: d3.js

I have a simple piece of JavaScript building a time axis in D3:

```
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
        .domain([testData.datapoints[0].at, testData.datapoints[testData.datapoints.length - 1].at])
        .range([0, (new Date(testData.datapoints[testData.datapoints.length - 1].at - testData.datapoints[0].at).getTime() / interval) * 21]),
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks([d3.time.minute, 15]) /* This line causes an exception */
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S")),
```

[In the D3 documentation on Time Scales ticks](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#ticks) it says

```
While to create ticks at 15-minute intervals, say:

    scale.ticks(d3.time.minute, 15);
```

But I get an exception:

> Unhandled exception at line 9204, column 7 in d3.js
>
> 0x800a138a - JavaScript runtime error: Function expected

(N.B. moving the offending line from the `xAxis` chain to the `xScale` chain makes no difference, it still throws the same exception in the same place. Changing the offending line to

```
        .ticks(20)
```

removes the exception but is not the functionality I am after.)

The D3 line where the error is thrown is the last line of this function in d3.js:

```
scale.ticks = function(interval, skip) {
  var extent = d3_scaleExtent(scale.domain()), method = interval == null ? tickMethod(extent, 10) : typeof interval === "number" ? tickMethod(extent, interval) : !interval.range && [ {
    range: interval
  }, skip ];
  if (method) interval = method[0], skip = method[1];
  return interval.range(extent[0], d3_time_scaleDate(+extent[1] + 1), skip < 1 ? 1 : skip);
};
```

At the point the exception is thrown `skip` is undefined.

What's wrong with the line of D3 JavaScript? It is copied from the documentation, but I doubt it's a bug in D3, more likely I have misapplied it somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this:

```
.ticks([d3.time.minute, 15])
```

But what you want is this:

```
.ticks(d3.time.minute, 15)
```

The array would be only if you're passing a specific list of values into the function. And in that case you'd want to use the [.tickValues](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickValues) function